# How to upload a video in comments using Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've been trying this for so long, but i can't achieve it...

If i upload a video in `/comment` node it always spits me this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"..."}}
```

If i'm going to upload images it just works fine.

This is my curl request so far..

```
curl -svX POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{obj_id}/comments?access_token=EAA..." -F "message=Hello World!" -F "source=@./sample.mp4"
```

Comment: I suspect you may need [publish_video permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/publish_video), but the documentation does not really make it 100% clear for your case.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i already have that permission in my Long-Lived token, its weird... Idk why i'm getting permission error even if i have met all permission needed.